# Apache POI Border style not working

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to make a thick border for a cell

```
CellStyle topBorderStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
topBorderStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THICK);
Row row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(0);
cell.setCellStyle(topBorderStyle);
```

As a result a cell does not have a thick border

Comment: Be sure this cell and row style wouldn't set by subsequent operation. It would cancel any decision taken before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the style on `cell` instead of `cell1`.
Also I think you should be using `HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK`

Try this:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
Row row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(0);
cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

I just tried it out and it works.

Comment: I added a few changes, try it out and see how it works